# Config Tabline position in vim-airline

Tags: vim, vim-airline

I did installed vim-airline for vim. But when i use tabline for list all buffer, its position is not wrong. I try to found any config in airline's help page but not found.

What i expect my tabline work. It should above status bar:
[[image: What i expect my tabline work. It should above status bar[1]]

What happend in my desktop :/
[image: What happend in my desktop :/]

Comment: Apart from the fact that you installed largely pointless plugins there's nothing wrong in your screenshot.

Comment: @romainl so hard to handle buffer when that tabline is above. So i want make it go to bottom like default.

Comment: Take a good look at that official GIF: the fake tabline is at the top of the window and the statusline is at the bottom. In your screenshot, you also have the fake tabline at the top and the statusline at the bottom so everything is normal. Now, AFAIK there's no way to move that fake tabline elsewhere. Either you get used to it or you disable it. How to do it is certainly explained in the plugin's documentation.

Comment: @romainl oh. I didn't see that point in GIF. Thank you!